# Multiple scroll bars on the same page

Tags: javascript, performance, scroll, synchronize

I am interested in have multiple scroll bars on the same page....seen a couple of examples mainly on ecommerce stores like www.jrew and www.indumenti.se  ,does any one have any ideas on the best way to structure the java script?  I also want to time the scroll bars to be synchronise also, ideally at the same speed.

Comment: scrollbars? Don't you mean slideshows/Carousel?

Comment: scroll bars dont use javascript, they are added by the browser when a element is larger then its parent. (unless disabled by css).

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for. Can you give a specific example of what you mean from the links you provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make any container scrollable with `overflow: scroll` or `overflow-y: scroll`. The general approach is to fix the height of these containers so they scroll. E.g.

```
.scroll {
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* enables momentum-scrolling on iOS */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

To split the scrolling views into multiple containers you would make e.g. a grid layout like normal and put a nested scrolling div inside. e.g.

```
<div class="row row-6">
    <div class="scroll">
        your left content
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row row-6">
    <div class="scroll">
        your right content
    </div>
</div>
```